# How can I create a loop in R for plotting multiple datasets in sequence?

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I'm new to R. I wrote this piece of code for plotting a dataset, giving the plot a meaningful title and saving it as an image:

```
#Define all the values I need
MyFile <- "Spectrum.csv"
MyTitle <- gsub(".csv", "", MyFile)
MyImage <- gsub(".csv", ".png", MyFile)
MyData <- read.csv(MyFile)
#Select the relevant range in the dataset
MyData_select <- MyData %>% 
  filter(Wavelength >= 400 & Wavelength <= 1000)
#Plot the dataset
p1 <- ggplot() + geom_line(aes(y = Reflectance, x = Wavelength), size=1, data = MyData_select) +
      scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(400,1000,100)) +
      scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale()) +
      theme(text=element_text(family="Arial"),
            panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_blank(),
            axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
            panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=0.5))
#Give the plot and the axes meaningful titles 
p1 + labs(title = MyTitle, x = "Wavelength (nm)", y = "Reflectance (arb. unit)")
#Save the plot as a png image
ggsave(MyImage)
```

The problem is that I have hundreds of those datasets in one directory and I would like to loop the code above to produce an image with the titled plot for each of them.

I tried to work around something like this:

```
FileList <- data_frame(filename = list.files())
for (i in FileList) {
  #Do the plotting/saving stuff
}
```

I really cannot find the way to make it work. In particular, I'm not sure how to use "i" in the rest of the code. Any help will be appreciated, and thank you for your patience... it's a steep learning curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (MyFile in list.files()){
    print(MyFile)
    ## do other stuff
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Replacing the first line of code with `for (MyFile in list.files()){` and adding `}` at the end just did what I needed. Thank you!